# Set the background color of the entire webpage (the browser's window)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have very little experience with html, css, etc so probably this looks like a stupid question to those that are used to create web pages.
But I cannot manage to set the background color of the entire window.

I mean the browser's window.

For example: [imgur](http://imgur.com/)

What I've already tried is setting the background color of the *body* with, of course, no success.

Any help/link would be appreciated.

*EDIT:*

Probably, due to my English, I cannot explain what I mean. I'll try again.
In the link I've posted, the web page is in the center of the screen (as 99% of the web sites).

This is the body, isn't it ?

No problems in changing the bg color of it so please stop posting obvious answers.

I need to change the bg color of the columns at the right and left side of the body, as in the link I've posted.
So, I guess there's a way to set a color/texture of the entire window, not only the body.

Comment: You cant change the color of the browser, I dont see nothing special in the  link you are pointing

Comment: Setting background color of body should work, meaning that you possible have another div above body with another background color.

Comment: @bto.rdz: the _special_ thing is that all the browser window is filled with a texture, not only the webpage.

Comment: Looking at the CSS for the site, there doesn't appear to be a texture applied to the body, though there is a background image applied to the banner.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Robert: I don't know how it's done (I guessed a texture but it's only a guess) but I'd like to do the same. Please see my question, I edited it.

Comment: @marco the body is the entire page, including the space you can set background color. The centered part is just a div inside a body.

Comment: @Imgonzalves:  You're right. I don't know why setting the bg color of the body didn't work but this made me think that the body was the center part and not all the window. OK, thanks to all.

Comment: @lmgonzalves Maybe on `imgur` this might look different, but if you want to access the whole "Browser's window" - as asked - you need to act on `<html>`, as `<body>` is only the entire page (the visible part) but might be only a fraction of the entire window (if the body is smaller than the window).  Hence you must act on `<html>` (CSS `html` instead of `body`) or something like `document.body.parentElement.style.backgroundColor`.  But you are in "good company", as - ironically - the lonely correct answer was downvoted below 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marco -

The body background of the page is a solid color, but they do apply an image (texture) to div elements on the page.  I think this is what you are trying to duplicate.  See the css in the example below, especially the background: url();  The texture they use is very subtle and not easy to see on my screen.

image url:
http://s.imgur.com/images/main-bg.png

You can inspect the site yourself using the developer tools of your browser (usually press F12) and looking at the styles applied to the page.

This is the actual style from the page:

```
#fullbleed-bg {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 429px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: url("//s.imgur.com/images/main-bg.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Run the snippet to view:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("//s.imgur.com/images/main-bg.png") 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer as the most detailed but thanks to all the others as well.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong as it acts on `body` and not `html`, see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427976/490291 -- but not downvoting as adding a bg picture might be a solution (I am unsure).

Comment: @Tino you should refer to w3 documentation instead of announcing your downvotes on every answer: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds

Answer (score 3):

Setting the background-color of the body element should work. If you have uncolored parts on the sides, set margin and padding to 0 as well. You might also have another element with a background color that is overlapping the body element and that is why you don't see the color.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Downvoted!  The **entire webpage** is the `<html>` element from which the `<body>` might be only a small part.  In CSS this is `html` (instead of `body`) and in JS this is `document.body.parentElement.style.backgroundColor` and not `document.body.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: That goes against w3 recommendations and is wrong. If you set `background` on `body`, it will be used in `html` as well.

See docs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *background-color* tag, which can be read about more in-depth at W3C http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

An example use of this would be the following:

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body style = "background-color: red;">
```

Comment: Downvoted!  See my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427976/490291

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qpLhgcg/) how to change body

```
<body>
    <div>
        some text
    </div>
</body>

body{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
}

div{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted! See my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427976/490291

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color name or hex/RGB value to set the style directly on the body tag

```html
<body style="background-color=red">
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the html selector in your external stylesheet, as so:

```
html {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, as I think **this is the only correct answer** here, because there is no other answer which acts on the whole browser window and not only on a (perhaps) small part of it (like `body`).  For the benefit of the reader, in JS you reach the **color of the `html` element via `document.body.parentElement.style.backgroundColor`**

Comment: Wrong: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds